# I want to validate an url with a regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegExp in JS and I am using `.test()` method for validating the url:

```
new RegExp(/^((https|http):\/\/www\.)?(www\.)?[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+(\/)?(\/[a-z0-9]+(\.(php|html|asp|aspx))?)?$/i)
```

I want a RegExp that can validate this types of url (notice things like http and https):

```
https://www.page.com/about.php
https://www.page.com/about 
https://www.page.com/  
www.page.com
page.com
page-10.com
1234.com
```

This RegExp works when I try those url except when I try this url:

```
www.page
```

It takes that url as true, and I don't know why...

**First part** of my regexp says: the url could have `https|http://www.` or `www.` at the beginning or none of them.

```
/^((https|http):\/\/www\.)?(www\.)?
```

**Second part** says: after first part there will be letters, numbers, some simbols + **a dot** (here is where my error comes from I think. Why it doesn't recognize the dot?) + more letters, the result could be something like **page-10.com**

```
[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+
```

**Third part** is optional, it allows a slash and an extension like page.com **/about.php**:

```
(\/)?(\/[a-z0-9]+(\.(php|html|asp|aspx))?)?$
```

***Question:***
In the second part I expect a dot when I say: `\.`, but it doesn't recognize it, how can I be explicit and ask for it?

Comment: This part of your regex `[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z]+` matches the `www.page`, the rest of the parts of regex are optional in this case

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url to specification URL validate regexes. You need specific URLs to validate only?

Answer (score 2):

I break your regex to parts:

```
^
((https|http):\/\/www\.)? # Match http://www. or https://www. OR NOTHING
(www\.)? # Match www. OR NOTHING
[a-z0-9_-]+\. # Match at least 1 character in group [a-z0-9_-] followed by a dot
[a-z]+(\/)? # Match at least 1 character in group [a-z] followed by "/" OR NOTHING
(\/[a-z0-9]+(\.(php|html|asp|aspx))?)? # Match at least 1 character in group [a-z0-9] followed by a web page file extension OR NOTHING
$
```

As you can see, the parts which have "**OR NOTHING**" has no meaning if it does not appear in your test string. So your test case of `www.page` is matched by the following parts:

```
[a-z0-9_-]+\. # Match at least 1 character in group [a-z0-9_-] followed by a dot
[a-z]+(\/)? # Match at least 1 character in group [a-z] followed by "/" OR NOTHING
```

Then you have the answer to your question:

> **Question:** In the second part I expect a dot when I say: ., but it
>   doesn't recognize it, how can I be explicit and ask for it?

---

The fixed version of your regex:

```
^((https|http):\/\/)?(www\.)?([\w-]{2,}\.[\w-]{2,3}\.[\w-]{2,3}|[\w-]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})(\/[a-z0-9]+(\.(php|html|asp|aspx))?)?$
```

Match test result: https://regex101.com/r/wGp68e/6

Comment: Thanks you for answering, I was testing your regexp but it has some problem like: ww-w.page.com (this return true), even it could allow whatever in the first part like: wwwwpage.page.com

Comment: In your edited answer I just found 1 error: if after the first dot there is wrote 2 or 3 letters, symbols (-_) or numbers then it returns true and before the first dot you could write strings without limit. This returns true: `1234567._-d` (but by the way, it just happens when there is 2 or 3 characters after the dot :) )

Comment: I fixed the case you pointed out. Let me know if there is any error.